# Mostrar resultado de un input en un div

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando hacer una simple funcionalidad donde inserto un nombre en un input y que cuando pulse el botón me aparezca en el div vacío. No logro hacerlo. Si hay ayuda se agradece :)

Dejo el código:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () =>
  {
   var nombre = document.querySelector('#nombre').value;
   var muestra = document.querySelector('#muestra');
   var boton = document.querySelector('#boton');

   boton.addEventListener('click', function()
   {
    muestra.innerHTML = 'Tu nombres es: ' + nombre;
   });
  });
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="name">Nombre</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="nombre">
  <br><br>
  <button type="button" id="boton">Mostrar nombre</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para resolverlo te falta el div con id="muestra" y debes obtener el valor del input "nombre" dentro de tu función:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () =>
  { 
    var muestra = document.querySelector('#muestra');
    var boton = document.querySelector('#boton');

    boton.addEventListener('click', function()
    {
      var nombre = document.querySelector('#nombre').value;
      muestra.innerHTML = 'Tu nombres es: ' + nombre;
    });
  });
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="name">Nombre</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="nombre">
  <br><br>
  <button type="button" id="boton">Mostrar nombre</button>
</form>

<div id="muestra">
```